# Save the times an action has happend then do something Netlogo

Tags: netlogo, patch

I dont have code as I dont really know how to do it. i have some patches of colore brown and at random the turn green for one tick and then they become brown again, it loops. I want to know if there is a way to ask a turtle to know how many times that patch has changed to green.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variable like you describe is often called a counter. In this case, you probably want it to be a `patches-own` variable so that each `patch` can individually track how many times a given event has occurred. In the example below, `times-turned-green` starts at zero (by default, that is the value for any variable declared in Netlogo) and the `patches` all update their own 'personal' `times-turned-green` whenever they change colour.

```
patches-own [ times-turned-green ]

to setup 
  ca
  ask patches [ set pcolor brown]
  reset-ticks
end

to example
  repeat 100 [
    ask patches [
      set pcolor brown
      if random-float 1 < 0.05 [
        set pcolor green
        set times-turned-green times-turned-green + 1
      ]
    ]  
  ]  
  ask n-of 5 patches [
    show times-turned-green    
  ]
end
```

Output in the Command Center should look similar to:

```
(patch -6 14): 2
(patch -9 4): 6
(patch 2 1): 8
(patch -3 3): 4
(patch -5 12): 5
```